# ReactJS component state returns empty data even after being set successfully in jest / enzyme tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple method to fetch data from an API and update state in the `Grid` component

```
//in the constructor
this.state = {
    blogs: []
};

//method here
updateBlogsTable() {
    Axios.get("/api/blogs").then(response => {
        this.setState({ blogs: response.data.data });
    });
    //omitting catch block for brevity
}
```

This method is called from `componentDidMount` and Refresh button's `click` handler

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateBlogsTable();
}
```

and

```
<Button
    id="refreshBlog"
    icon="pi pi-refresh"
    style={{ float: "right" }}
    onClick={this.updateBlogsTable}
/>
```

The test for Refresh Button fails

```
describe("Blog Grid", () => {
  let response = {
      data: {
          data: [
              {
                  title: "title one",
                  published: false,
                  publish_date: null,
                  slug: "title-one"
              },
              {
                  title: "title two",
                  published: false,
                  publish_date: null,
                  slug: "title-two"
              }
          ],
          links: {
              self: "link-value",
              first: "http://adminpanel.test/api/blogs?page=1",
              last: null,
              prev: null,
              next: null
          },
          meta: {
              current_page: 1,
              from: 1,
              path: "http://adminpanel.test/api/blogs",
              per_page: 20,
              to: 2
          }
      }
  };

  it("refreshes blogs", () => {
      axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));
      const grid = mount(<Grid />);
      let refreshResponse = Object.assign({}, response);
      refreshResponse.data.data.push({
          title: "title three",
          published: true,
          publish_date: null,
          slug: "title-three"
      });
      axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
          Promise.resolve(refreshResponse)
      );
      grid.find("#refreshBlog")
          .at(0)
          .simulate("click");
      expect(grid.state().blogs).toEqual(refreshResponse.data.data);
  });


});
```

`grid.state().blogs` returns `[]` which fails the test.

```
FAIL resources/js/tests/Blogs/Grid.test.js (5.765s)

  Blog Grid
    ✓ renders without errors (235ms)
    ✕ refreshes blogs (161ms)

  ● Blog Grid › refreshes blogs

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
```

When I add `console.log(this.state.blogs);` to the `updateBlogsTable()` method; I can see

```
console.log resources/js/views/Blogs/Grid/Grid.js:25
[ { title: 'title one',
    published: false,
    publish_date: null,
    slug: 'title-one' },
  { title: 'title two',
    published: false,
    publish_date: null,
    slug: 'title-two' },
  { title: 'title three',
    published: true,
    publish_date: null,
    slug: 'title-three' } ]
```

How come `grid.state().blogs` is still an empty array in the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since promise.gets invoked asynchronously, as soon as you simulate button click, your state will not get updated.

I had faced similar issue while testing my components too and one way I could think of fixing the problem was - return the promise from your `updateBlogTable` and subscribe to `then` in your test and have the assertion within that `then`.

Something like this -

```
updateBlogsTable() {
  let p = Axios.get("/api/blogs").then(response => {
      this.setState({ blogs: response.data.data });
  });
  return p;
}

grid.instance().updateBlogsTable().then(() => {
  expect(grid.state().blogs).toEqual(refreshResponse.data.data);
})
```

Even I want to know if it can be tested directly by simulating button click.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: is there a way to callback promise immediately like timeout construct?

Comment: As far as I know there is any way to immediately invoke the promise callback. Btw how do you immediately invoke timeout construct?

Comment: I'm actually not sure no what I wanted there; something like `{method,0}` makes it return immediately perhaps? Quite a noob at JS so just wondering.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to immediately invoke `then`. It has to go through the event loop.

Comment: I've moved all API fetch operations to a separate library which resolves and promise and sends data and I call this library functions in methods in Components. That was I have a cleaner separation of concerns and easier mocking for my tests.